# Windows starts only at second try (Ubuntu and Windows 10 Dual Boot on same HDD)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 as dual boot next to Windows 10. I obviously got each system on its own partition and I got a swap partition as well.

The problem is that if i switch from Ubuntu to Windows, Windows doesn't start at first try. Grub2 shows Windows as bootable option and I land on the loading screen of Lenovo, but the window freezes after a while. After I "kill" my laptop with the power button, Windows starts without any problems. Ubuntu always starts without problems.

I hope any of you can help me because it's very annoying to always boot Windows twice.

Comment: Hmm. Problem like this cured me of urge to use Windows. I suspect you have security/UEFI issue. Can you tell us about your install process.  Did you fiddle system settings? Other idea: Linux puts system into state Windows cannot understand. Two avoid problem in short term, SHUTDOWN from Linux, restart to go to the dark side. Why? The first OS you use can load some firmware that lingers on a warm restart. This used to be a big deal with "win printers" and network cards.

Comment: Have you checked the [health of your storage device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) an intermittent failure to boot leads me to suspect the possibility of impending complete media failure at the sector containing the Windows boot record.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some need settings. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info